# Calling a function listed inside a prototype

Tags: javascript

```
CircularCountDown.prototype = {
    init: function () {
        this.formatData();
        this.draw();
        this.start();
    },
    start: function () {
        if (typeof this.data.beforeStart == "function") {
            this.data.beforeStart(this);
        }
        this.show();
        this.starDecrementTimeEvent();
        var time = this.getFormattedTimeByCircle();
        this.animate(time);
    },
    starDecrementTimeEvent: function () {
        var that = this;
        console.log(that);
        this.decrementTimeEvent = setInterval(function () {
            that.time -= 1;
            that.setTime(that.getStringTime(that.time));
            if (that.time <= 0) {
                that.time = 0;
                that.stopDecrementTimeEvent();

                if (typeof that.data.end == "function") {
                    that.data.end(that);
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
    },
    stopDecrementTimeEvent: function () {
        clearInterval(this.decrementTimeEvent);
    }
}
```

I'm using a plugin for a circular timer and I'm looking to call the stopDecrementTimeEvent function to stop the timer in a different JS file. Im not familiar on how to call it in this format.

Any guidance would be great, thanks.

Comment: Does calling `.stopDecrementTimeEvent` work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm using a plugin for a circular timer and I'm looking to call the stopDecrementTimeEvent function to stop the timer in a different JS file. Im not familiar on how to call it in this format

You'll have an *instance* that you've created via `new CircularCountDown`, e.g.:

```
var theInstance = new CircularCountDown(/*...args here if needed...*/);
```

The instance (object) that creates will have the object that `CircularCountDown.prototype` refers to as its *prototype*, meaning that it inherits all of its properties.

So you just call `stopDecrementTimeEvent` on that instance:

```
theInstance.stopDecrementTimeEvent();
```

That will find the property `stopDecrementTimeEvent` on the prototype, then call it with `this` referring to the instance (object), which will have the timer handle in its `decrementTimeEvent` property, ready to be used by `stopDecrementTimeEvent`.

Comment: This will not work if you create 2 instances in of `CircularCountDown`  in the two different JS files (The question does specify "in a different JS file") You will need to create a factory, or pass the `theInstance` into the other file

Comment: @NicholasRobinson: Being in separate files has not bearing on the matter whatsoever.

Comment: If you have `var theInstance = new CircularCountDown(/*...args here if needed...*/);` is both JS files, calling `start` in one file and `stopDecrementTimeEvent` in the other file `this.decrementTimeEvent` will not be defined in the later instance of `theInstance`

Comment: @NicholasRobinson: The OP didn't say they were doing that. They just said they were calling it "in a different file." It's certainly *possible* they might be doing something like that (or any of a dozen other things :-) ), but they haven't said they are.

Comment: That is why I said "This will not work **if** you create 2 instances..."

Comment: @NicholasRobinson: I don't think speculating about the various things that *could* go wrong is really useful here.